# Go to last line of data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have poked around and found the following code that will advance to the last line on data in our Google Spreadsheet- at least until we add more lines beyond row 297.

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("B297");
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to write this script so that it will go to the last line of data, regardless of the line number.

Is there a change that I can make to this code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

The method `getLastRow()` tells you the last row of a sheet that has data. This can be used to move the selection to that row. Another thing I changed in the sheet selection: your script always operates on the first sheet; it makes more sense to operate on whichever sheet is  active currently.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

This can be placed into the spreadsheet menu using onOpen.

By the way, pressing Ctrl + ArrowDown does the same thing, if you do it in a column that has some data in every row (like the date or Id column).

Answer (score 2):

The script below allows you to go to the last cell with the content of column A. It works even if some cells in the column A contain formulas.

Modifying the number in parentheses in `lastRowOfCol(1)` allows you to reach the last cell with content from another column.

Additionally, you can also change the focus to the first empty cell after the last one with content.

```
function onOpen(){
  lastRowOfCol(1); //Enter the column number you want to use as the base of the search
}

function lastRowOfCol(column){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var total = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,column,total).getValues();
  for(var i=total-1;values[i]=="" && i>0; i--){}
  var last = sheet.getRange(i+1,column);
  //var last = sheet.getRange(i+1,1); //Option to fetch the last row of a given column, but to position in column 1
  //var last = sheet.getRange(i+2,column); //Option to go to the cell below the last one with content 
  sheet.setActiveSelection(last);
}
```

Script from Marcelo Camargo in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs-pt/y_OsMcbYU8Y;context-place=topicsearchin/docs-pt/marcelocamargo$20function$20UltimaLinhaDaColuna(coluna))

Answer (score 0):

The currently relevant option that works on all non-hidden sheets, and not just on the active one:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheets = ss.getSheets()
  const properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
  const lastActiveSheetName = properties.getProperty("lastActiveSheetName")
  let lastActiveSheet

  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    if (!sheet.isSheetHidden()) {
      const sheetName = sheet.getName()
      const lastEdit = properties.getProperty(sheetName)  
      if (lastEdit) {        
        if (sheetName !== lastActiveSheetName){
          sheet.getLastRow() // Without this magic does not work - I could not figure out the reasons
          sheet.getLastColumn() // Without this magic does not work - I could not figure out the reasons
          const [lastRow, lastCol] = lastEdit.split(',')
          sheet.getRange(Number(lastRow), Number(lastCol)).activate() // With focus set to this cell
          //sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange(Number(lastRow), Number(lastCol))) // Without setting focus to this cell
        }    
        else {
          lastActiveSheet = sheet
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if(lastActiveSheet){
    lastActiveSheet.getLastRow()
    lastActiveSheet.getLastColumn()
    const [lastRow, lastCol] = properties.getProperty(lastActiveSheetName).split(',')
    lastActiveSheet.getRange(Number(lastRow), Number(lastCol)).activate() 
  }
}

function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet() 
  if (!sheet.isSheetHidden()) { 
    const cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    const row = cell.getRow()
    const column = cell.getColumn()
    if (row !== 1 || column !== 1) { // Protection from the evil magic of "self-editing" the first cell
      const sheetName = sheet.getName()
      PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(sheetName, `${row},${column}`)
      PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("lastActiveSheetName", sheetName) 
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Please note that in the code I do not use a semicolon separator - it's more convenient for me.